# Windows Password Changed, no longer able to use Git. No Credential Manager in Control Panel

Tags: git, authentication, git-clone, change-password

Basically, what the title says.  I needed to change my Windows password, and now I get an authentication error when I try to use git clone:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for '<git repo here>'
```

So far I've tried the following:

```
git config --global --add user.password "password here"
git config --global --unset user.password
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

With no change apparent.  I've also tried restarting git bash, Intellij, and my computer.  Most of my search has boiled down to "use Credential Manager in Control Panel," but I don't seem to have it on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command to set the config on a global level.

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```